# Return "parent" rows where only one "child" record exists in one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, mariadb, relations

Having a one-to-many relation, I am trying to get records in the `accounts` table where only one record exists in the `accounts_prop` table.

I have the following query, but it does not do the desired. The query returns records with more records in the `accounts_prop` table.

```
select *
from `accounts` 
where exists (
    select *
    from `accounts_prop` 
    where `accounts`.`account_id` = `accounts_prop`.`account_id` 
      and `von` >= '2017-08-25'
    having count(account_id) = 1
) limit 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Setup sample data:

```
create table accounts (account_id int, von datetime);
insert into  accounts (account_id, von) values (1,'2017-08-01'), (2,'2017-09-01'), (3,'2017-10-01');

create table accounts_prop (account_id int, propname varchar(30));
insert into  accounts_prop (account_id, propname) values (1,'pname1'), (2,'pname1'), (2,'pname2'), (3,'pname1');
```

Sample data joined together:

```
select a.account_id,
       a.von,
       ap.propname
from   accounts a
join   accounts_prop ap
on     a.account_id = ap.account_id
order by 1,2,3;

account_id | von                 | propname
---------- | ------------------- | --------
         1 | 2017-08-01 00:00:00 | pname1  
         2 | 2017-09-01 00:00:00 | pname1  
         2 | 2017-09-01 00:00:00 | pname2  
         3 | 2017-10-01 00:00:00 | pname1
```

Proposed query:

```
select a.*
from   accounts a
where  a.von >= '2017-08-25'
and    (select count(*)
        from   accounts_prop ap
        where  ap.account_id = a.account_id) = 1
order by 1,2;

account_id | von                
---------- | -------------------
         3 | 2017-10-01 00:00:00
```

Here's a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=fbaa757a70dba8189041a2cbc0593119) for the above.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Just saw that you were asking for MySQL. This won't work as MySQL has no support for analytical functions.

The following should work on MySQL now ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4fa2dc/10/0)):

```
SELECT
    accounts.*   
FROM
    accounts
JOIN accounts_prop 
    ON accounts.account_id = accounts_prop.account_id
    AND von >= '2017-08-25'
GROUP BY accounts.account_id
HAVING count(1) = 1
LIMIT 3
```

---

Old Solution:

One way to tackle this would be using a window function to count rows by account_id and filtering on that:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        accounts.*,
        count(1) OVER (PARTITION BY accounts.account_id) row_count
    FROM
        accounts
    JOIN accounts_prop ON
        accounts.account_id = accounts_prop.account_id AND von >= '2017-08-25'
) sub
WHERE row_count = 1
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: From the OP's comment on my answer, they might actually be using **MariaDB**, if that matters.

Comment: Then my first solution might even work. Don't have access to MariaDB test instance unfortunately to verify

Comment: the query alone works if I do not use where statemant

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `COUNT()` stuff without grouping your data with a `GROUP BY` clause.

Try this:

```
SELECT `accounts`.*
FROM `accounts` 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `accounts_prop`.`account_id`
    FROM `accounts_prop` 
    WHERE `von` >= '2017-08-25'
    GROUP BY `accounts_prop`.`account_id`
    HAVING COUNT(account_id) = 1
    ) AS `accounts_prop`
    ON `accounts`.`account_id` = `accounts_prop`.`account_id`
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Adding group by does not solve the problem in my case

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Try my new edit.

Comment: this has some syntax errors

Comment: I don't actually have MySQL installed on my machine, so I can't test out the syntax errors... Did you try Werter's answer to your question?

Comment: on mariadb does not work

Comment: I fixed some of the syntax errors.